# Scripts collide with each other - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a page wich is, basically, a list of divs; it doesn't matter how they're structured, suffice it to say that they're all visible by default. There are buttons on the page that lets you sort through them thanks to a java script. For example, if you click on the button "complete", the page shows only the divs containing the code

```
<div class="ended">complete</div>
```

while if you push on the "show all" button, it returns to show them all. (The structure is something like

```
<div class="entry">
      <p>something</p>
      <div class="ended">complete</div> 
et cetera </div>
```

I've recently decided to add a new button, that picks a random div through them all. It all works well, except that when you try to show them all again after picking a random one, it doesn't work.

I'm not really all that familiar with JavaScript and JQuery (the random script I adapted from a script I found here), so I dont' understand what's wrong.

This is the code for (one of) the sorting script:

```
$('#completed').click(function() {
    featureList.filter(function(item) {
        if (item.values().ended == "complete") {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

And this is the code for the "show all" button:

```
$('#filter-none').click(function() {
    featureList.filter();
    return false;
});
```

Finally, this is the code for the "random" button:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#random').click(function () {
    var E = document.getElementsByClassName("entry");
    var m = E.length;
    var n = parseInt(Math.random() * m);
    for (var i = m - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      var e = E[i];
      e.style.display = 'none';
    }
    E[n].style.display = '';
  });
});
```

Comment: It seems to me there's a lot of information missing from this question. For example, I have no idea what type `featureList` has. Can you make a jsfiddle that's a bit more complete? [I've started one for you here](http://jsfiddle.net/3eY7k/).

Answer (score 0):

Hard to give an answer without knowing what's going on inside the .filter-function but based on what you've provided this could work:

```
$('#random').click(function () {
    var entries = document.getElementsByClassName("entry");
    var numEntries = entries.length;
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * numEntries);

    var counter = numEntries;
    featureList.filter(function(item) {
        counter--;
        if (counter === random) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

I'm assuming the elements for which `false` is returned inside .filter are hidden somehow.

Since 'Show all' and 'Show only completed' is working, using the 'Show only completed'-way of hiding the wrong elements in 'Show random' should work.